# Using Scala SNA

Tags: scala, maven, sbt, sna

I want to use SNA in scala. I am using sbt to manage my dependencies.

At [SNA](http://code.google.com/p/scala-native-access/) you can see `import net.java.dev.sna.SNA`
But I can't find it in [Maven](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Csna)

How would I use SNA in my Scala project if I can't find it in maven? There is also a [Svn trunk](http://code.google.com/p/scala-native-access/source/browse/#svn/trunk/src/net/java/dev) But I don't know what I should do with it.

Update 1:

I manged to get it "working" by just copy & paste the [SNA.scala](http://code.google.com/p/scala-native-access/source/browse/trunk/src/net/java/dev/sna/SNA.scala)
And I had to add `class SNAException(msg:String) extends Exception(msg)` because it was missing.

Comment: relevant: http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/4692